# Can Windows 7 assign arbitrary tags to files?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, metadata, tags

Is there anything in Windows 7 that allows me to assign tags (ie. "Important", "Family", "Private") to files and then search by them?

For example, let's say I have pictures organized into directories like this:

```
\Photos\Baby\Birth

\Photos\Baby\Easter

\Photos\Family\Christmas
```

Now I'd like to tag individual pictures (or videos, documents, etc) inside those folders so I can do a search.

That might be a bad example but hopefully you get the idea. I'm hoping I don't need a third party application (because I'd like to tag any kind of file; not just pictures)

EDIT: I just saw that tags are built into Windows 7 but only for certain (very few??) file types. Can this be expanded or changed to include all file types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to find a tag based file manager?](http://superuser.com/questions/78473/where-to-find-a-tag-based-file-manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 doesn't natively have tagging of any sort [aside from a few file formats that already support it in the file specifications](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file) (like, say, mp3 which has the ID3 tagging specification).  You can add FOLDERS to libraries, but to do individual files like you want it will require a third-party application.